# Ruby - How to remove a setter on an object

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, setter, remove-method

Given a class like this:

```
class B
    class << self
        attr_accessor :var
    end
end
```

Suppose I can't modify the original source code of class B.  How might I go about removing the setter on the class variable var?  I've tried using something like B.send("unset_method", "var="), but that doesn't work (nor does remove_method, or overwriting that method with a var= method that doesn't do anything).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class <<B ; remove_method :var= ; end
```

Comment: Awesome!  I forgot about doing things like that!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class B
  class << self
    undef var=
  end
end
```

You may want to use remove_method instead:

```
class B
  class << self
    remove_method :var=
  end
end
```

To see the differences, go to:
http://www.nach-vorne.de/2008/2/28/undef_method-remove_method/

Comment: This results in Error

NameError: method `var=' not defined in Class